# one file paste into multiple folder with folder name

Tags: directory, rename, batch, paste, copy-and-paste

I Have one report file (1.xls) this 1.xls should copy into all name folders
c/desktop/test/     inside the test folder i have this file 1.xls and i have the folders also aaa_001
bbb_002
ccc_003
I need to paste 1.xls into all folders and 1.xls should be renamed as per folder name.i want like this:
c/desktop/test/aaa_001/aaa_001.xls
c/desktop/test/aaa_001/bbb_002.xls
c/desktop/test/aaa_001/ccc_003.xls
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash script to do what you need. It might also be worth thinking about using links if you want your files to automatically update. Just be aware that some archive formats pack the links as links instead of the actual file if it's a soft link.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# put all arguments into the args array
args=("$@")
# get your single source file from argument one
src=${args[0]}

# loop over the arguments array, each value is put into $p
idx=0
for dst in ${args[@]}
do
  # skip the first argument
  if [ ${idx} -gt 0 ]
  then
    # copy file
    cp ${src} ${dst}
  fi
  idx=$((${idx} + 1))
done
```

Then you just call your script with the first argument as the singular source and all following arguments as the destinations

Alternatively you can use `xargs`

```bash
# delimited by new lines `\n`
echo '/path/to/dir1\n/path/to/dir2' | xargs -I{} cp 'file/to/copy' {}
```